# An efficient way to diagonalize a sparse vector in R

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, diagonal

I'm working with a vector (~14000x1) of various values that I would like to put on the diagonal of a sparse matrix where I'm using the library Matrix. I want to do this while avoiding the need of creating a full matrix and then converting back to a sparse matrix after.

So far I can do this with a for loop but it takes a long time. Can you think of a more efficient and least memory-intense way of doing it?

Here's a simple reproducible example:

```
library(Matrix)
x = Matrix(matrix(1,14000,1),sparse=TRUE)

X = Diagonal(14000)

for(i in 1:13383){
  X[i,i]=aa[i]
  print(i)

}
```

Comment: what about using indexing ie `sparseMatrix(i=1:10, j=1:10, x=rnorm(10))` , where `x` is the diagonal values, or whats wrong with `Diagonal(10, rnorm(10))` . (
hmm maybe i dont think i understand what you want

Comment: yeah it's easier than I thought. Thanks for your help. I guess I was getting caught up because Diagonal() didn't seem to accept a sparse vector, but it works nicely with a full vector as you exemplified. Not too difficult in the end.